# kotlin admob ad not shown

Tags: kotlin, admob

I try to add adMob Intersiciel in app in Kotlin
I ve follow the docs (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start and https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#kotlin_1)
But the ad is not shown(But no any error on the app in the emulator) So I need of your help.
I think the problem is come from "Set the FullScreenContentCallback"in the doc. Could you confirm that the code need to be in a function eg loadAd and "Show the ad"in a function showAd"which to be call when needed> Or maybe do you know a tutoriel to find the solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem> When I test with an test id ad mob, I have not the ad show at each time> I don't know why> So my problem is solved